# limitation on count of records returned by ls -lrt

Tags: ls

Is there any limitation on count of records returned by `ls -lrt`?
I am seeing problem of crash in OEL 4.7 environment where my `ls -lrt` command may return more than 100K records.

Comment: Is `ls` the shell or the terminal crashing?

Comment: OEL 4.7 is pretty old. Is the coreutils rpm up-to-date?

Comment: Hitting a limitation should never cause a crash but an error message and error exit code.

Comment: With huge amounts of data the sorting becomes a problem. Does `ls -lU` crash, too?

Comment: Not tried the ls -lU:( as it is a prod environment

Comment: @ayankumarbasu Does that make sense? Why should you run `ls -lrt` in a production environment but not `ls -lU`?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to run ls on a directory with over 30-40k files will just have ls run out of memory and die. This is because it's trying to run stat() on all the files before outputting them.

There is no strict limitation in the source though.